# "There is ... on the road" vs "the road has..."

Tags: questions

I came across the sentence:

> **there is** more traffic **on the road**

Could I build up a sentence like this one below

> **the road has** more traffic

being sure that the meaning is still the same?

If yes, could you explain me this in detail?

Answer (score -1):

The gross meanings are the same, and both sentences are correct. The first (*there is...*) is in the passive voice, while the second (*the road has...*) is active. Which one you should use depends on how you want to sound and what you want to emphasize.

Passively voiced statements - such as most of this answer - tend to be flatter, drier, and raw statements of fact. Active statements are more engaging, and convey the subject's agency. Notice how in the second it sounds more like *the road* is doing something, rather than simply sitting around and just happening to have greater traffic.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that the *there is...* structure is in passive voice.

Comment: This is not a passive verb. A passive verb is formed from some form of "be" plus a past participle. Moreover, only transitive verbs can take a passive form.